# Is it correct here to say that "...more was to come"

Tags: grammar, past-continuous, future-continuous

The following is a paragraph of the NY Times news:

> It was not clear whether the action was the totality of the Iranian response to the killing of the scientist …, **or whether more was to come.**

Is the bolded parts correct? In my opinion it should be  **or whether more is coming.** Since I think we are talking about an action that has not yet taken place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two differences between your expression and the original. The tense of "was" is different, and the present participle "coming" is different from the infinitive "to come".

These two expression mean about the same:
More **was** to come
More **was** coming
They express the anticipation from a past perspective. For that expression, it doesn't matter whether a response has happened at the time the sentence is read. It could refer to the present moment, or it could be used to describe an event in history.

More **is** to come
More **is** coming
These expressions are set in the present, and the writer assumes that the reader is in the same present as they are.

There is a slight difference between the present participle and the infinitive. The present participle "coming" suggests that some response is already set in motion. The infinitive "to come" means that something will happen, but the response may not have started yet. But that is a very fine distinction, so in this context, they mean about the same thing.

The writer chose the perspective of "whether more was to come", and it's not incorrect. Your expression "whether more is coming", and "whether more is to come" are also grammatical, and have a different time perspective.